# change background color on webpage jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility

I am trying to make a website for seniors to use and therefore i am providing options so that they can change the background color and font color on the page. e.g. white on black and black on white

I have successfully implemented the jQuery to do this. however, when i click on one of the options for example, the black on white and then i want to click onto the white on black option... both of them apply. The page does not restart to just apply one of them, they overlap and both color options apply. I am not sure how to fix this so i was wondering if anyone could help me.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="Col">Col</a>
<a href="#" id="Color">Color</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Col', function(){
    $('#wrap, .headerphone, nav, .slider, .intro, .wrap, .services, .column, p,      h1, h2, h3, h4, ul li, ol, li, .clearfix, .highlight, a, footer, .footer-  distributed, .footer-links').css({'background-color' : '#000000', 'color' :   '#FFFFFF'});
});

$(document).on('click', '#Color', function(){
    $('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, ul, li, ol, .highlight, a, span, .footer-links,   .headerphone').css({'color' : '#000000'});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You changed `background-color` in the first one, but you only change back `color` in the second one.
2. You have a different selector in the second one. If you want to change everything back, you should have the same selector.

Note: I recommend using `addClass` and `removeClass` instead the `css` function. That way you could add/remove a class only to the `body`, and achieve the same thing.